# django path module in main project

Tags: django, path

I have a django project that when I do `python manage.py runserver"`, I get `ImportError: Could not import settings citizenkane.settings (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): cannot import name utilcommands`.

```
citizenkane                # main project
├── manage.py              # has "has "from utils import utilcommands"", does not work
├── citizenkane            # main app for project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
│   ├── wsgi.py
├── nature                 # an app for the project
│   ├── __init__.py        # has "from utils import utilcommands", works ok
│   ├── models.py
│   └── views.py
├── tiger                  # an app for the project
│   ├── __init__.py        # has "from utils import utilcommands", works ok
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
└── utils
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── utilcommands.py
```

For some reason, when I have "from utils import utilcommands" in citizenkane/citizenkane/**init**.py, I get the error mentioned above. However, the same import statement is all in citizenkane/nature/**init**.py and citizenkane/tiger/**init**.py and there are no problems.

What do I need to do to be successfully able to include the `"from utils import utilcommands"` in citizenkane/citizenkane/**init**.py?

*update for @vishen*

Here is my manage.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "citizenkane.settings")
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Can you show your manage.py file?

Comment: Did you check if the citizenkane main project directory is in your sys.path?